# excel not refreshing all pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to refresh pivot tables using vba.
I have code that modifies the underlying table query, and refreshes the query.
Once that is done, it refreshes the pivot tables, which in turn will refresh a summary sheet. For some reason, the final pivot table is not being refreshed. It will refresh normally.

Methods tried:

1.

```
Dim PC As PivotCache
For Each PC In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    While DateDiff("s", PC.RefreshDate, Now) > 60
    PC.Refresh
    Wend
Next
```

2.

```
Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Pivot2").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Pivot3").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Pivot4").PivotCache.Refresh
```

3.

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

I have tried including a `DoEvents` before refreshing pivot tables, after the refresh of the tables has occurred.
I have also tried copying the file to another file, and recreating it there. the effect stays, it simply moves to whichever pivot table it considers the last one created.
File size is 279Kb as xlsb, and 336 Kb as xlsm.
Data for the tables is coming from SQL server 2012, and all tables are on the same excel sheet. The tables are updated, but the pivot is not.

Comment: just a thought ... what if you put a hard `Application.Wait` statement after the data refresh?

Comment: no luck with `application.wait`. adding a `MsgBox` and forcing a wait that way doesn't help either.

Comment: Try by (re)setting data source range of the pivot in code before refresh.

Comment: @PankajR, `Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotCache.SourceData = "Table1"` (etc) - no change

Comment: Could it be that the data didn't change for that particular table and so it refreshed but you don't notice a difference?

Comment: the code actually changes the dates returned by the queries. I can see the tables have changed to the selected dates, and all but one of the pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Sub refreshTables()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have your automatic calculations turned off.

Comment: I have it off, but after the refresh of the pivot tables, I execute this sequence of commands: `Application.CalculateFullRebuild : 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True : 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: If you keep calculations on, does it make a difference?

Comment: no, and refreshing after the full recalc doesn't work either.