# After deleting rows from an excel sheet, pivot tables doesn't refresh

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

My 50 MB Excel file, have a sheet with raw data, and about 400 pivot tables all linked with the data sheet. Each pivot table with his own filters.
After deleting some thousand rows with a vba macro in data sheet, the pivot tables doesn't refresh to new values, neither, forcing it manually, nor by means of the macro in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421515/excel-not-refreshing-all-pivot-tables).
¿Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to re-wire them all up to data source again.

Comment: I was afraid, someone telling me that...

Comment: use structured data to avoid this, meaning use tables instead of keeping your data in a plain sheet, you can also write few lines of code to change the data source for all of your pivot tables

Comment: @framontb Does every pivot table have the exact same data source? If so, you could loop through them all.

Comment: (Based on dwirony comment) It seems that this workaround works: delete all the data in the data sheet > refresh > put the data again > refresh. Need to validate, but it seems all pivot tables were refreshed.

Comment: @framontb yeah, but what will you do if you want to delete some data again? still it will cause you the same problem, insert a table where you have your data and then when you select the data for the pivot table it will show the table name only since Excel recognizes the table databody as the dataset, then if you add or delete rows everything will be working just fine, you would only need to refresh you pivot table. Instead of manually changing the data source for 400 pivot tables, you can do it using a very short VBA code. Do it once manually while recording a macro and then put it in a loop

Comment: @Ibo. OK, you are right. I will try.